# Is there a way to structure my package in a cleaner way?

Tags: python, package

So, I'm a beginner at creating packages.

My package looks like this:

```
mypackage/
    data/
    notebooks/
        notebook1.ipynb
    src/
        __init__.py
        subpck1/
            __init__.py
            A.py
            B.py
        subpck2/
            __init__.py
            C.py
            D.py
```

I feel like there's something missing. Say module a is in A.py. At the moment, from the notebook, I have to import or call a using src.subpck1.A.a. It's quite cumbersome and I don't like users of the notebooks having to write src.

I've tried:

```
# src/__init__.py

import src.subpck1.A

a = src.subpck1.A.a
```

And now I can just import src and call src.a. It's less cumbersome, but is there a clean way to not use src at all. Or do I even need to call it src? I plan on sharing the repository with colleagues so I want it to look professional.

Comment: generally, `src` is not part of the *package* structure, the it merely "holds" the package structure, so it shouldn't have an `__init__.py`

Comment: And you want to make your package *installable*, i.e. you actually need to *package your package*. See [the official docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and note, you don't have to actually build and upload distribution archives, but with following the stups up to there, your project should be able to be "pip installed" from source and then the imports will work correctly (without having to mess with the PYTHONPATH or working directory)

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the source contents in the `mypackage/` directory (if you;re not going to be adding a ton of other components/files to the root directory). But, if you're going to add folders like `tests/`, `docs/`, `samples/`, `build/`, and build files, src would be a good way to consolidate the main project code (usually this is done for minification). If not, though, you could move them to mypackage/ and import in the notebook as:

```
from subpck1.A import a
```

Comment: `src` is a good practice, even if you don't really need it at the moment. but it shouldn't actually be part of the package structure